# Aplicar eventos con Javascript a elementos de una clase

Tags: javascript, html, eventos, dom

Tengo una consulta un poco tonta quizá pero no me puedo dar cuenta de como hacerlo, quiero hacer esto mismo pero con *Javascript* puro:

```
$('.clase').click(function(){
   $(this).toggleClass('activo');
});
```

Lo que no logro hacer con *Javascript* puro es aplicarle el evento a todo los elementos que tengan esa clase, ya que cuando quiero agregar un *addEventListener*  a un elemento que seleccione según la clase.

Me tira error porque me pide que agregue el número de indice de ese elemento, pero yo lo que quiero es aplicarlo, no a un elemento en particular, sino a todos los que tengan esa clase.

**javascript**

```
var boxProducto = document.getElementsByClassName("box-producto");

    for(i=0;i<boxProducto.length;i++){
        boxProducto[i].addEventListener("click",function(){
            alert("hola");
        });
    }
```

Porque no me funciona?

Comment: Hola @AlejandroLariccia, bienvenido a SOes, te invito a que te tomes el **[tour]** y revises estos enlaces: [ask]

Comment: Alejandro , su código funciona , https://repl.it/IHoj/2

Comment: la única razón por la cual no funcione el código que publicas es que no hayas definido la clase `box-producto` en ningún **elemento que soporte** el evento `onClick`

Comment: Deberías agregar un [mcve].

Answer (score 5):

**Puro JavaScript**:

```js
//Seleccionas todos los elementos con clase test
var divs = document.getElementsByClassName("test");
    
    //Recorres la lista de elementos seleccionados
    for (var i=0; i< divs.length; i++) {
        //Añades un evento a cada elemento
        divs[i].addEventListener("click",function() {
           //Aquí la función que se ejecutará cuando se dispare el evento
           alert(this.innerHTML); //En este caso alertaremos el texto del cliqueado
        });
    }
```

```html
<div class="test">Test1</div>
<div class="test">Test2</div>
<div class="test">Test3</div>
<div class="test">Test4</div>
<div class="test">Test5</div>
<div class="test">Test6</div>
<div class="test">Test7</div>
```

Espero que te sirva de ayuda

Comment: acabo de hacer esto: var boxProducto = document.getElementsByClassName("box-producto"); for(i=0;i<boxProducto.length;i++){ boxProducto[i].addEventListener('click',function(){ alert('hola'); }); } para probar aplicarle un evento click a todos los productos de clase "box-producto", y no me funciono, porque puede ser?

Comment: @AlejandroLariccia Pues lo que has puesto está bien, deberías mandarme tu código HTML entero también, y si tienes más fragmento de código js también te agradecería que lo enviaras.

Comment: El codigo html es el siguiente: 
<div class="box-producto">
   <div class="thumb">
    <img src="images/004632000F88356_1.jpg" alt="camiseta">
   </div>
   <div class="descripcion">
    <p>Camiseta de futbol adidas river plate away</p>
    <p class="precio">$849,00</p>
    <div class="limpiar"></div>
    <i class="adidas"></i>
    <p class="categoria">Camisetas futbol</p>
   </div>
  </div>

Comment: @AlejandroLariccia pff es que así se ve mal, intenta actualizar tu pregunta añadiendo todo tu código y me avisas.

Answer (score 0):

Sería algo más o menos así, (explicación en los comentarios del snippet):

```js
// Obtenemos todos nuestros elementos del árbol DOM 
// con la clase "clase"
var elementos = document.querySelectorAll('.clase');

// Recorremos cada uno de nuestros elementos
elementos.forEach(function(elemento) {

  // Obtenemos el texto dentro del div para identificarlo
  var id = elemento.firstChild.nodeValue;

  // Agregamos un listener a cada elemento
  elemento.addEventListener('click', function() {
    console.log('Elemento ' + id + ' clickeado');
    // Realizamos el toggle de la clase
    elemento.classList.toggle('clase2');
  });
  
});
```

```css
.clase {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  margin: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
  background-color: black;
  float: left;
  color: white;
  font-family: Verdana;
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.clase2 {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  margin: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
  background-color: salmon;
  float: left;
  color: white;
  font-family: Verdana;
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<div class="clase">1</div>
<div class="clase">2</div>
<div class="clase">3</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Puede recurrir a *getElementsByClassName* para obtener los elementos que poseen esa clase , para luego aplicar los eventos que desee , iterando sobre los elementos retornados por *getElementsByClassName*.

El funcionamiento de *toggle* se puede realizar usando la propiedad [classList](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Element/classList) del elemento , para aplicar el *toggle*

```js
var elements = document.getElementsByClassName("clase");
  for(var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++){
    elements[i].addEventListener('click',function(){
     /* Aplicamos el Toggle de la clase*/
      this.classList.toggle('nuevaclase');
 });
}
```

```css
.clase{
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
}
.nuevaclase{
    background: red !important;
}
```

```html
<div class="clase" style="background: #ccc;"></div>
<div class="clase" style="background: #cc1;"></div>
<div class="clase" style="background: #c2c;"></div>
<div class="clase" style="background: #14c;"></div>
```

Comment: acabo de hacer esto:

var boxProducto = document.getElementsByClassName("box-producto");

 for(i=0;i<boxProducto.length;i++){
  boxProducto[i].addEventListener('click',function(){
   alert('hola');
  });
 }

para probar aplicarle un evento click a todos los productos de clase "box-producto", y no me funciono, porque puede ser?

Comment: son elementos Div´s que contienen otros div´s con imagenes y descripciones , ejemplo:

<div class="box-producto">
   <div class="thumb">
    <img src="images/004632000F88356_1.jpg" alt="camiseta">
   </div>
   <div class="descripcion">
    <p>Camiseta de futbol adidas river plate away</p>
    <p class="precio">$849,00</p>
    <div class="limpiar"></div>
    <i class="adidas"></i>
    <p class="categoria">Camisetas futbol</p>
   </div>
  </div>

Comment: Ahi agregue el codigo javascript, pero como agrego el html sin que lo lea como html sino que muestre el codigo? perdon, soy nuevo aqui en stackoverflow

Comment: la consola no me marca ningun error, por eso no entiendo porque no me funciona